# Cannot get localstorage value from new Blazor Web App .NET 8?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to use [Blazored.LocalStorage](https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage) on the new Blazor Web App (.NET 8) and somehow it doesn't work like it should on Blazor Wasm.

`Program.cs` on both server and client project I use the simple config like this

```
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
```

On LocalStorageOnServer.razor page: (server)

```
@page "/localstorageonserver"
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@inject ILocalStorageService _localstorage;
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        _localstorage.SetItemAsync("currentCount", currentCount);
    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        var count = await _localstorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("currentCount");
    }
}
```

It shows the error:
JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the `OnAfterRenderAsync` lifecycle method.

How come it says the component is being statically rendered even though I set **rendermode** to Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering) related:

> During prerendering:
>
> An interactive connection to the user's browser doesn't exist. The
> browser doesn't yet have a page in which it can run JavaScript code.
> localStorage or sessionStorage aren't available during prerendering.
> If the component attempts to interact with storage, an error is
> generated explaining that JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued
> because the component is being prerendered.

disable prerender

```
// prerender would be enbaled by default
-@rendermode InteractiveServer
+@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer(prerender: false)]
```

or move your codes to `OnAfterRenderAsync` method as mentioned in error message

Comment: thanks, i understand it, I already used it on OnAfterRender with StateHasChange